# Istio ingress with httpRewrite failed to load additional resources

Tags: url-rewriting, minikube, istio, kubernetes-ingress

On `minikube` VM I have two `k8s` services: `service-v1` and `service-v2`.
I have `istio-ingress` rule:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: forecast-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "istio"
spec:
  rules:

  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /v2/.*
        backend:
          serviceName: service-v2
          servicePort: 8080

  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /v1/.*
        backend:
          serviceName: service-v1
          servicePort: 8080
```

So when I access the `/v1/endpoint` it forwards the call to `service-v1`.
In my application, I have a mapping for `/endpoint` and not for `/v1/endpoint`, so I have also an `httpRewrite` rule:

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: RouteRule
metadata:
  name: ingress-service-v2-rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  destination:
    name: service-v2
  match:
    request:
      headers:
        uri:
          prefix: /v2
  rewrite:
    uri: /
  route:
  - labels:
      version: "2.0"
---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: RouteRule
metadata:
  name: ingress-service-v1-rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  destination:
    name: service-v1
  match:
    request:
      headers:
        uri:
          prefix: /v1
  rewrite:
    uri: /
  route:
  - labels:
      version: "1.0"
```

But now I have another issue: when I'm accessing `/v1/endpoint` from the browser, it makes another call to my service to another `/endpoint2` and it gives me `404` as this endpoint can be accessed as `/v1/endpoint2`. And I can access `/v1/endpoint2` from the browser.
The only way that I can see to fix it is by changing the code to make a call to relative URL like this: `../endpoint1`. Is this the only option? Are there any other options how to get around this issue?

Comment: Same problem here, did you find a solution?

Comment: @ChrisG. did not find any other solution. I have changed my code to make the requests to relative path `../endpoint1`, that is a workaround, but it works for my case.

Comment: Ok, thanks for reply. I am trying change the index.html to point directly - maybe the same. Thanks

Comment: @ChrisG. no worries, glad to help